# Dynamic memory deletion within functions

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic

this is my first post, so sorry if it is not asked well.

Basically I am having trouble with dynamic memory and i would like to know if it is me misunderstanding the concept, or at least one of the functions. Ok, so i'm using C++ where I need to manage an array that changes size within the main program loop but i keep getting a heap error when i try to delete the memory. (below is a simplified version of  what i'm trying to do).

```
void main(void)
{
  //Initialization

  //main loop
  while(true)
  {
    int* array;
    function(&array);

    printf("test %d",array[0]); //basically use the data

    delete [] array;
  }
}

//in separate file

void function(**int val)
{
   *val=new int[size of array] // i pass the size of the array...
                               //to the function as well
   //fill the array with data
   return;
}
```

Ok so after this i can read the data so it must be attached to the pointer "array" but then why would it not allow me to delete the data as if it was already deleted?

Any advice would be much appreciated thanx.

Comment: can you post the original code, seems like you might be smashing your stack.

Comment: That code won't compile; you have `**int val` in the argument list in a function declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, in its current state, *should* work. However, it is very bad practice to use `new` and `delete` like that, *especially with new/delete in different places*.

You should use `std::vector` instead:

```
// main function 
std::vector<int> array = function();

printf("test %d",array[0]); //basically use the data
```

And your function() would be:

```
std::vector<int> function()
{
  std::vector<int> val(size);
  //fill the array with data
  return val;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not the main problem but you actually have the syntax wrong here,

```
void function(**int val);
```

It should be:

```
void function(int **val);
```

But you don't need a double pointer as you can simply pass the pointer by-reference:

```
void function(int *&val);
```

It follows that your program should be like this:

```
int main() // main should return int
{
    int *array;
    function(array, 5);

    printf("test %d", array[0]);

    delete [] array;
}

void function(int *&val, int size)
{
   val = new int[size];
}
```

You also didn't need the `while (true)` loop either.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing the exact same thing.  Only thing I would add is that I believe the original issue was, after the double pointer, vs pointer by reference issue, when  you tried to use the delete[], it was probably not a correct time to use the array delete and should have actually just been delete, because of the way you did your reference, vs de referencing, etc, you didn't even have access to the pointer you could have properly called delete[] on.

Comment: oh, my bad, that was a typo but also a good suggestion (about the double pointer) thanx

Comment: but I was intending to delete the data connected to the pointer not the pointer itself should i still use just delete?

Comment: You can't delete the "pointer".  You call delete on the pointer to free the memory it is pointing to.  The pointer simply goes out of scope.  Even after delete array, or delete[] array, array is still a valid entity, and could be re used to point to another bit of memory.

Comment: @user2448431 You're not deleting the pointer, you're deleting the memory it points to. Use `delete[]` for pointers to arrays created through `new[]`. Use `delete` for pointers assigned by a regular `new` expression. The pointer has automatic storage duration and will go out of memory by the end of main.

Answer (score 2):

You said that "any advice" was welcomed, so here's my advice:

Don't use C-style arrays in the first place, and this won't be a problem.  Use a `vector` instead:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void main(void)
{
  //Initialization

  //main loop
  while(true)
  {
      std::vector <int> array;
      function (array);
      printf ("test %d", array[0]);
  }
}
```

//in separate file

```
void function(std::vector <int>& vec)
{
  vec.push_back (1);
  vec.push_back (2);
  // ...etc...
}
```

Above is a basic and naive implementation that uses a `vector` instead of C-style arrays and dynamic memory management.  There are many opportunities for improvement, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea.  The value in passing things by reference is the copying cost of large objects.  With pointers you don't need to worry about this.  This code could be cleaned up like this as well.

```
int main() // main should return int
{
    int *array = function(SOME_SIZE);

    printf("test %d", array[0]);

    delete [] array;
}

int * function(int size) //Just return the pointer
{
   int *temp = new int[size];
   return temp;
}
```

Since we're dealing with pointers... returning them isn't a big deal, and is typical practice when you need to "transfer" ownership of a dynamically allocated object.  That being said, the post that references using vectors or other standard containers is the best approach.  Avoiding use of new and delete makes code much safer.

Comment: yea, the problem with that is i need to return several arrays from the same function. However it's clear that the whole new and delete thing isn't great and i should change it up to std::vectors.

Comment: I'm glad you've acknowledged vectors are better.  I'm curious though, how you think your function differs from mine on your point of "returning several arrays".